# Is it possible to set the content source of a post with Tumblr's API?

Tags: api, tumblr

I find it strange that you can set nearly every property of a given post through Tumblr's API, however, I cannot seem to find how one would go about setting the content source of a post when posting through Tumblr's API.

Any thoughts? By the way, not the source of the `quote` post type, but rather the `content source` that you would if you used their GUI.

Comment: AFAIK, the `source` refers to reblogged posts, it links to the first instance of the post. This explains why you can't set it via the API as Tumblr handles this logic when you reblog a post.